# Apend a URL stored in a variable in curl command

Tags: shell, curl, applescript

I am facing some problem when i am storing a string called "http://juke.com" in a variable called domain. and the rest is the filename stored on the domain server. i.e. ipurl.php so that it becomes "http://juboapp.com/ipurl.php" as complete URL.

And when i call this variable in the below code it stucks over there and never proceeds. Basically it gives a syntax error when not in try mode. Can someone tell me what is the proper syntax for it.

```
{set ipurl to (do shell script "curl -d \"ipurl=ipurl" & " \" & domain " \" /ipurl.php")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
set domain to "http://juboapp.com"
set iPurl to (do shell script "curl " & domain & "/ipurl.php")
```

URLs don't require quotes around them in this case.

Comment: i tried this. but it gives me a syntax error.


`sh: -c line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: I am trying to achieve the below line:


set loginusername to "maddy"
set domain to "http://juboapp.com"

`set ipurl to (do shell script "curl -d \"username=" & loginusername & domain & "/ipurl.php")`

I am sending one parameter to the server for validations..
The above code is not working. Please help.

Comment: Please can someone tell me how to give a new line. shift enter doesnt work.!!

Comment: @maddy2011 `return` will give you a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer. I have used GET method instead of a POST method and it worked. Though it also works with the above answer from fireshadow52, but i wasn't able to get it to work with a parameter in it. thanks though. If anyone could get this working with a parameter in the POST method then please comment!

Here's the code:

```
set domain to "http://juboapp.com"
set logindetails to domain & "/addplaylist.php?username=" & loginusername & ""
set logindetails to (do shell script "curl " & logindetails)
```

Thanks!